# Suffixing a double with f in C programs

Tags: c, floating-point, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suffix of “f” on float value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026570/suffix-of-f-on-float-value)

Is there a different suffix to be used with type double or is it the case that "f" works for both?

Comment: It's a suffix, and anything with a decimal and no suffix is a double.

Comment: @Chris Yeah! Had a long day sorry..

Answer (score 2):

An undecorated floating point literal like `1.5` has type `double`. The suffix `f` makes the type `float` (as in `1.5f`), and `L` makes it `long double` (as in `1.5L`).

Comment: Is %f the format used to print doubles?

Comment: @saadtaame, Yes, one will be converted to the other when passed in as a variable argument, so there's no way for the function to tell them apart.