# Declaration of a variable

Tags: c, variables, variable-declaration, letter

I am new in C programming language and I have a question related to a variable:

```
float a=12.34f;
```

What does "f" stand for? I tried to see what happens if I remove the letter, but I couldn't find anything. The output is the same.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2

Comment: "*The output is the same.*" but not the compiler output, which warns that a `double` is truncated to `float` (without the `f`). Stop using `float` anyway, it's so 20th century. You wouldn't use `char` for numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that it will be interpret as float not double by the compiler.

See here:
[Suffix of "f" on float value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026570/suffix-of-f-on-float-value)