# Can a C++ define macro rewrite a float literal as a double literal or at least drop the f postfix?

Tags: c++, macros

```
#ifdef DOUBLE_PRECISION_COMPUTE
    #define MAKE_PRECISE(N) ...
#endif
// if not defined, leave as it is. MAKE_PRECISE(N) (N)
```

Can above macro (replaced "..." with the right redifiniton) do the below operation?

```
double PI=MAKE_PRECISE(3.14159265359f);
```

becomes

```
double PI=3.14159265359;

double area= MAKE_PRECISE(3.14159265359f)*r*r;
```

becomes

```
double area= 3.14159265359*r*r;
```

Comment: Do you have C++14 available?

Comment: is `MAKE_DOUBLE` and `ADD_PRECISION` supposed to be the same symbol?

Comment: Just made up those names, yes same intention. Edited, now all are MAKE_DOUBLE. I need to drop the f at the and. No, I don't have C++14 available yet but I can try later. Now I'm in C++11

Comment: `static constexpr auto PI = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288` should work I guess?? Apple defines it as `#define M_PI        3.14159265358979323846264338327950288` in Objective-C. Any particular reason you need it to be prefixed as a float? I guess I'm wondering what the point of `MAKE_PRECISE` is.

Comment: _"Edited, now all are MAKE_DOUBLE."_ Except, no, they're not; they're all `MAKE_PRECISE`. Your attention to detail is invisible.

Comment: @Brandon [This question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5026570/2096401) gives some of the effects of using `f` (to do with whether or not arguments get promoted to `double` or not). Not quite sure either why it would matter or need to be selectable, but...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

There is no way to transform a token using preprocessor directives.

Instead, correct the literals by removing the `f` in your source code.

The result will anyway be far easier to read than wrapping everything in some `MAKE_PRECISE` macro that is unclear as to what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, you cannot strip the `f`, but you can conditionally add it:

```
#ifdef DOUBLE_PRECISION_COMPUTE
#   define MAKE_PRECISE(N) (N)
#else
#   define MAKE_PRECISE(N) (N##f)
#endif
```

which will turn:

```
double area = MAKE_PRECISE(3.14159265359)*r*r;
```

into either:

```
double area = (3.14159265359)*r*r;   // with DOUBLE_PRECISION_COMPUTE defined
```

or

```
double area = (3.14159265359f)*r*r;  // with DOUBLE_PRECISION_COMPUTE UNdefined
```

Comment: The preprocessor's token pasting operator `##` comes in handy