# getting garbage value while finding area of a circle

Tags: c

i tried to find the area of the circle and found a garbage value. I m using a gcc compiler

area of a circle

```
#include<stdio.h>  
void main() 
{
    int a=1;
    float c;
    c = 22/7 * a * a;
    printf("%f is the area" , c);
}
```

3.142857 is the area should be the output.
but it is showing 
3.000000 is the area

Answer (score 1):

`22/7` is *integer* division so will truncate to `3`. You need something like:

```
float c = 22.0 / 7 * a * a;
```

---

And, as an aside, `22/7` isn't *that* good a representaion of PI. `355/133` would be better but *much* better than that would be (on systems where it is available):

```
#include <math.h>
// Now use M_PI
```

or (on systems where it is not):

```
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
```

---

There's also very little reason to use `float` types when `double` variables have more range and precision. Single precision `float` variables can be useful if you have a *lot* of them and want to reduce storage space but, in most other cases, it's worth just using double precision.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a garbage value, the operation you are performing on all the integers, take a look

```
22/7 * a * a
```

here variable a is integer, as well as 22 and 7, so the complete operation's end result is int and it get converted into the float c variable which results 3.0000.

to solve this, write:

```
 22/7.0 * a * a
```

Answer (score 1):

> 3.142857 is the area should be the output. but it is showing 3.000000 is the area

You might be thinking because you have a `float` data type on the left-hand side of your assignment operator, the computation on the `right-side` of your assignment operator should be a float computation.

However, `C` programming language won't promote the variables to `float` implicitly. It will do integer division and multiplication and after computing the result, the result (which will be an integer) will be implicitly casted to the data type on the LHS of your assignment operator (i.e., float).

To learn more about integer division, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division). It says:

> 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators
>
> 6 When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.88) If the quotient a/b is re-presentable, the expression (a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a.

So, you were getting `3.0000` because according to integer division, `22/7` is `3` (fractional part discarded) and after multiplying with `a` twice, you will get an integer of value `3`. To assign the computed value of the expression to your variable `c`, language does the implicit conversion to float having a value of `3.000`.

To solve your problem, you need to explicitly use variables or constants of type `float` on RHS of your assignment operator or you can use explicit casting operator.

```
float c = 22.0f / 7 * a * a;
```

Because of higher associativity of division operator, `(22.0 / 7)` will be calculated first and their result will be a float as one of operand (`22.0` and `7`) is a float constant. Then, the result of the expression will be calculated and `integer` operand will be promoted to `float` data type. At the last, your result (which is float) will be assigned to your variable `c`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026570/suffix-of-f-on-float-value) link to learn about the difference between `22.0` and `22.0f`.