# Differences between using variable and using direct number in C language

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I have such a program

```c
int a = 100;
float b = 1.05;
printf("%f\n", a * b);
printf("%f\n", 100 * 1.05);
```

Its output looks like this:

```
104.999992
105.000000
```

I understand that `104.99992' is due to floating-point precision issues. But why does the use of direct numbers not result in a loss of accuracy?

Comment: Well `1.05` is considered a **double**. Try `100 * 1.05f` you should see similar results.

Comment: Possible duplicate, [What's the use of suffix `f` on float value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026570/whats-the-use-of-suffix-f-on-float-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a * b` uses `float` arithmetic. `100 * 1.05` uses `double` arithmetic.

Your C implementation probably uses IEEE-754 binary64 for `double` and binary32 for `float`.

`1.05` is a `double` constant. The decimal numeral `1.05` in source text is converted to the nearest representable `double` value, which is 4728779608739021•2<sup>−52</sup> = 1.0500000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125.

`float b = 1.05;` converts that value to `float`. The result of the conversion is the nearest representable `float` value, which is 4728779393990656•2<sup>−52</sup> = 4404019•2<sup>−22</sup> = 1.0499999523162841796875.

When `b` is multiplied by 100 in `float` arithmetic, the result is the representable `float` value that is nearest the real-arithmetic result. It is 13762559•2<sup>−17</sup> = 104.99999237060546875.

When that is printed with six digits after the decimal point, the result is “104.999992”.

In `100 * 1.05`, only `double` arithmetic is used; there are no `float` values. When the `double` 1.0500000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125 is multiplied by 100, the result is the `double` nearest the real-arithmetic result. It is 105•2<sup>0</sup> = 105. When that is printed with six digits after the decimal point, the result is of course “105.000000”.

Summary: There are generally rounding errors in floating-point arithmetic. In `float` arithmetic, they are easily visible when more than a few digits are printed. In this example with `double` arithmetic, the rounding errors happened to cancel—the `double` nearest 1.05 was slightly above 1.05, so the rounding in the conversion rounded up. Then, when that was multiplied by 100, the `double` nearest the real-arithmetic result was slightly below it, so the rounding in the multiplication rounded down. These effectively canceled, producing 105.

If you execute `printf("%f\n", 100*1.05f);`, `1.05f` will be converted directly to `float` instead of to a `double`, and the multiplication will be done with `float` arithmetic,<sup>1</sup> and you will see the same result as for `a * b`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The C standard allows extra precision to be used, but generally you will see the same result here.