# What is the significance of 0.0f when initializing (in C)?

Tags: c

I've seen code where people initialize float variables like this:

```
float num = 0.0f;
```

Is there a significant difference between this and just doing the following below?

```
float num = 0;
```

Thanks.. :)

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. ["f" after number/float in Objective-C/C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391818/f-after-number-float-in-objective-c-c)

Comment: They probably left off the f once.  Once bitten, twice shy.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**float x = 0** has an implicit typecast from int to float.
**float x = 0.0f** does not have such a typecast.
**float x = 0.0** has an implicit typecast from double to float.

Depending on the compiler, implicit typecast can require the compiler to generate extra code.

Comment: If you have a compiler that does the typecast at runtime, you have bigger performance problems than an extra typecast.  The only exception is when the exact floating-point scheme is selectable at runtime, in which case the compiler can't necessarily know what the right typecast is (although it's obvious in this case).

Comment: Yep, last time I saw the issue was on a Vax C compiler.

Comment: ie bloating the executable (slightly)? This isn't something a 4k executable contest competitor would consider acceptable is it.

Comment: I think promotion is the correct term. not typecast.  All compilers would have to do it, not just vax c

Answer (score 10):

Probably the reason is that they once wrote something like:

```
float f = 1 / i; // i an integer
```

Having debugged that, they swore always to decorate literals sufficiently to get the right type:

```
float f = 1.0f / i;
```

In this case, the `.0` is to ensure that the division is floating-point, not integer division. The `f` is because there's no need for the operation to be done in `double` -- I expect there's more chance of an implementation where `1.0/i` would be significantly slower for no benefit (software float emulation, indifferent optimization), than one where `1.0f` is significantly slower for no benefit (if double is faster than float that's because you have fp hardware, so conversion between the two will be very fast, so not introduce *significant* slowdown).

One you've got into the habit of decorating literals, you might well write:

```
float f = 0.0f;
```

even though it has exactly the same effect as `float f = 0.0;` or `float f = 0;`.

Of course the author might not have gone through this revelation personally, they might just have inherited the style of someone else who did.

I'd just write `0`.

R.. points out in a comment an another answer that writing 0 also has the benefit that when you change the type of `f` in future, you don't have to update the literal to match. And if the assignment is separate from the definition, then changing:

```
float f = something
// some time later
f = 0.1f;
```

to:

```
double f = something;
// some time later
f = 0.1f;
```

is probably a bug. Better to use `0.1` and let the compiler truncate to float if necessary. You could probably argue that using `float` at all is an optimization, for space if not for time, and the burden of dealing with any differences between float and double should be counted as a developer cost of performing that optimization.

Answer (score 7):

It's just considered good practice to initialise a variable with a literal constant of the same type. In this case you have a float variable and you should initialise it with a float literal constant, i.e. `0.0f`, rather than an int (`0`) which is then implicitly cast to a float.

Answer (score 4):

Well, strictly speaking, 0 is an integer, so `float num = 0` requires a casting from integer to float. But I suppose the compiler does this for you anyway. I guess people use `0.0f` in order to emphasize that this is a float, so nobody mistakes it for an integer.

Answer (score 4):

'f' indicates that you want a float :

**0 is an int**

**0f is a float**

**0.0 is a double**

**0.0f is a float**

Answer (score 3):

Paul R has written the answer. Your second example has an integer initialization value.

You should always use an initializer of the same type as the variable that is being initialized. This avoids any conversion at compile time (ideally) or run time (lazy compilers: are any this lazy, though?). And perhaps more importantly, conversion can lead to some strange things in the general case.

Here conversion should do exactly what is expected, but it is still good style and avoids a compiler warning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to use this for initialization process. But, for operations involving floating point literals, this would be useful. 
For example;

```
float a=0.43, b;
b = 0.5*a + 2.56*a*a;
```

Floating point literals without a suffix are considered doubles. So, for this computation, "a" will be type-casted to double and the final answer of RHS evaluation will be a double. During the assignment, the double value of RHS is casted to float and assigned to "b". This would degrade performance if the machine does not have double precision FPU. To avoid this and use float for entire computation. suffixes are used. For example,

```
float a=0.43, b;
b = 0.5f*a + 2.56f*a*a;
```