# What is the difference between the following initialization for float?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Initialization of float can be done as follows,

```
float a = 0.0
float a = 0.f
float a = float(0)
```

Is there any pros and cons to use any of these?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the significance of 0.0f when initializing (in C)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199338/what-is-the-significance-of-0-0f-when-initializing-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter at all.  You could also say `float a = 0;` and again it would be the same thing.  Or `float a = float();`.  I think the most conventional would be `0`, `0.0`, or `0f`; the rest are just redundant.

Comment: i think OP did not meant it in only the case of assigning zero.

Comment: I'll leave it to the OP to say what they mean, but if they mean other constant values too, everything I said still applies except the bit about `float()`.

Answer (score 0):

The first initializes from a double literal, whereas the second is from a float literal. The bits in the two zeros may not be the same.

The third is c++ constructor-like syntax that actually just does direct initialization, in this case from an integer literal.

Comment: The bits in a float initialized from a double 0 might differ from one directly from a float 0?  How?  IEEE 754 has only two ways to represent zero as far as I know, and one is -0 which neither of the above will give you.