# which function will run here? and error: call of overloaded ‘sum(int, int)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ so please bear me and see my problem and help me to solve my problem.

Here I just tried to know which function will execute if there is a more than one function with same name But I left with an Error

**error: call of overloaded ‘sum(int, int)’ is ambiguous**

MY CODE

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// A function with default arguments, it can be called with
//2 arguments or 3 arguments or 4 arguments.
int sum(int x, int y, int z=0, int w=0)
{
    return (x + y + z + w);
}
int sum(int x, int y, float z=0, float w=0)
{
return (x + y + z + w);
}
/* Driver program to test above function*/
int main()
{
    cout << sum(10, 15) << endl;
    cout << sum(10, 15, 25) << endl;
    cout << sum(10, 15, 25, 30) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Help what is happening here and what is the error I am getting an error

Comment: To help answer the question, you should share which of the two `sum` function you expect `sum(10, 15)` to call, and why you expect that.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know which of the two functions should be called either, that's why you get that error.

Comment: The problem comes from the parameter default values...  You could make ALL parameters to the second overload `float`s to make it work.

Comment: Because of the default arguments, `sum(10, 15)` could call the first version as `sum(10, 15, 0, 0)` or it could call the second version as `sum(10, 15, 0.0f, 0.0f)`. Neither one is better than the other, so the call is ambiguous.

Comment: @PeteBecker
Ya 
but if I remove the line cout << sum(10,15) << endl;
The code works good with rest of the two lines sum(10,15,25) ,sum(10,15,25,30)
but why??

Comment: If you remove `cout << sum(10,15) << endl` then you remove the problem because there is nothing ambiguous about calling the other two couts

Comment: The other two couts work because you passed at least 3  `int`s so it knows to call the `int sum(int x, int y, int z=0, int w=0)` there is no reason to prefer the `int sum(int x, int y, float z=0, float w=0)` over the `int sum(int x, int y, int z=0, int w=0)` one.

Answer (score 2):

Your ambiguity is on line

```
cout << sum(10, 15) << endl;
```

This is because compiler doesn't know if third argument is float or int

In this line:

```
cout << sum(10, 15, 25) << endl;
```

you are calling to:

```
int sum(int x, int y, int z=0, int w=0)
```

because your third argument is int, not float... if you had called it using

```
cout << sum(10, 15, 25.0f) << endl;
```

Compiler would have noticed that third argument was float and

```
int sum(int x, int y, float z=0, float w=0)
```

will be called.

You are always using ints on your code.
floats have to be written with dots. (0 is int, 0.0 is double, 0.0f is float)

```
int sum(int x, int y, float z=0, float w=0)
```

should be

```
int sum(int x, int y, float z=0.0f, float w=0.0f)
```

Edit: I've changed my answer following @Pete Becker comment. Appending f suffix to float constants (0.0f)

Ref:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Comment: In `float z=0.0`  the 0.0 is a double. `float z=0.0f` would be a float. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199338/what-is-the-significance-of-0-0f-when-initializing-in-c/5199515](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199338/what-is-the-significance-of-0-0f-when-initializing-in-c/5199515)

Comment: `float z = 0` is okay; there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `float`. Some people prefer using more closely-typed initializers, so for those folks, `float z = 0.0` or `float z = 0.0f` is preferable. Personally, I go back and forth on this one. +1.