# (numberf) What does it mean

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“f” after number/float in Objective-C/C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391818/f-after-number-float-in-objective-c-c)

I searched in internet, but i found nothing. So, what does mean whet near number is f character, like 3.0f or 4.6f . And what's the difference beetween normal number like 3.0 and [f] (:D) number like 3.0f . Thank you very much!